# UItableviewController doesn't load data

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

Hi guys i have a UITableviewcontroller class, i am calling it from otherview and pushing it on the navigationcontroller.

```
Streets_view_Controller_iPhone * street_controller = [[Streets_view_Controller_iPhone alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        street_controller.riding_number =  [assignment objectForKey:@"Riding_Number"];
        street_controller.polling_number = [assignment objectForKey:@"Poll"];




        [self.navigationController pushViewController:street_controller
                                             animated:YES];
```

and here is my tableview controller class
"Streets_view_Controller_iPhone.m"

```
#import "Streets_view_Controller_iPhone.h"


@implementation Streets_view_Controller_iPhone
@synthesize riding_number;
@synthesize polling_number;
@synthesize data;


- (NSString *)dataFilePathwithFilename:(NSString*)name
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    if (self)
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [riding_number release];
    [polling_number release];
    [data release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = @"Streets";

    NSString * filepath = [self dataFilePathwithFilename:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@.plist",self.riding_number,self.polling_number]];

    NSLog(@"%@",filepath);

    NSArray * streets = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

    self.data = streets;

    [streets release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView reloadData];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

   // return [data count];
   // NSLog(@"%d",[data count]);

    return 2;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * StreetLevelCell= @"StreetLevelCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             StreetLevelCell];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:StreetLevelCell] autorelease];

       // NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
       // NSDictionary * streets_data = [data objectAtIndex:row];
        //cell.textLabel.text = [streets_data objectForKey:@"Street_name"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.textLabel.text = @"test for streets";
        return cell;
    }



    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}

@end
```

But for some reason i amnot getting anything in the cell, just the title of the view i.e Streets . and empty table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing will show up in your table because of the following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 0;
}
```

You must have at least one section in your table for it to show any data.  Try `return 1;` and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks i know i was dumb to ask something like that